# How I can consume message form Kafka using KafkaTemplate without @KafkaListener in Java Spring? RabbitMQ analogue

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I want to declare topic in Kafka, send message in it, and the recieve message from this exact  topic. As I understood the easiest way to do it is using Kafkatemplate method send(), what also creates a topic. But how I can recieve the message form this topic without @KafkaListener, but using some method.
Recently I do the same alghritm for RabbitMQ. It was realized as below:

```
    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
```

And then

```
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;

    private void sendMessage(final String queue, final String message) {
        createQueueIfNotExists(queue);
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message);
    }

    private void createQueueIfNotExists(final String queue) {
        this.amqpAdmin.declareQueue(new Queue(queue));
    }

    protected String receiveMessage(final String queue) {
        Message message = this.rabbitTemplate.receive(queue);
        Strung result = messeage.getBody();
        return result;
    }
```

Can I do the same with KafkaTemplate?

Comment: You have to create a Kafka consumer for consuming messages from Kafka.

Comment: @Umeshwaran, Yeah, I found this class https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html but I don't actually realize how to recieve messeage from topic with it. Do u know it?

Comment: Yes,Please see my answer. I have been using Kafka for past 6 months . Also note that Kafka doesn't support priority processing of messages. So If priority processing is a need, you might want to look at other MQ's or you have to write a workaround on kafka

Comment: What's your use case for not using KafkaListener or Spring Cloud Streams / Spring Integration?

Comment: @OneCricketeer for testing

Comment: You can use `spring-kafka-test` package and still use a regular consumer separate from the code that uses `@KafkaListener` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing

Comment: @OneCricketeer There is used `@KafkaListener` in `KafkaConsumer` class setup

Comment: `@Component
public class KafkaConsumer` can be named anything. My point was that, that post seems to exactly answer what you wanted

Comment: @Umeshwaran hello again! I just have faced new problem. Can you help me again pls? I post me issue in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923342/consumerrecords-is-always-empty-in-kafka-java-but-futurerecordmetadata-isdon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache official Kafka client to create a consumer .

1.Using properties, create a kafka consumer
2.Assign or subscribe to a topic
3.Use the poll method to poll message

> Creating Consumer

```
 private static Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {
      final Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                                  BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                                  "KafkaExampleConsumer");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              LongDeserializer.class.getName());
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              StringDeserializer.class.getName());

      // Create the consumer using props.
      final Consumer<Long, String> consumer =
                                  new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

      // Subscribe to the topic.
      consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));
      return consumer;
  }
```

> Reading message

```
static void runConsumer() throws InterruptedException {
        final Consumer<Long, String> consumer = createConsumer();

        final int giveUp = 100;   int noRecordsCount = 0;

        while (true) {
           //polling the records since the last offset. 
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords =
                    consumer.poll(1000);

            if (consumerRecords.count()==0) {
                noRecordsCount++;
                if (noRecordsCount > giveUp) break;
                else continue;
            }
            //Printing the messages received in a for loop
            consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
                        record.key(), record.value(),
                        record.partition(), record.offset());
            });
            //committing the offset of messages in Async mode 
            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
        consumer.close();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
```

[For further reading on creating kafka consumers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_consumer_group_example.htm)

[Creating Kafka consumers](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-consumer/index.html)

Comment: Exact consumerrecord - it is single message, right?

Comment: ConsumerRecords is like a list of messages . You have to iterate through consumerRecords and consume messages.